# Is there any way to programatically scroll the watchkit interface controller

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have a setup that allows vertical scrolling to show some additional buttons.  Upon clicking one of these,  I'd like to snap the view back to it's initial (pre-scrolled) appearance.

I do not see any equivalent to UITableView.scrollRectToVisible in the Watchkit sdk.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get is the `scrollToRowAtIndex:` method on  `WKInterfaceTable` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceTable/scrollToRowAtIndex:)). In your case, you can simply scroll to row 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
func scroll(to object: WKInterfaceObject, at scrollPosition: WKInterfaceScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

as of WatchOS 4. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2874208-scroll?changes=_1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that at this time, I'm afraid.  The only WatchKit element capable of scrollTo: is, as [Mike Swanson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207805/mike-swanson) mentioned, the `WKInterfaceTable` element.  And even then, you can only scroll to make a cell visible, not to any specified offset.

Even if you hack something together where you nest your whole UI in a single `WKInterfaceTable` cell, you *still* will not be able to achieve the behavior you desire, as it will only ever scroll so far as to have the bottom edge of the cell align with the bottom edge of the screen, with the rest spilling up and off the top.